# Applying 2 different ASC markups sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering why my function would not work using sql and what is the best way to apply this markup. Here is the code:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY user_id ASC, (SELECT * FROM user WHERE hits > 40 ORDER BY hits) DESC";
```

I have provided a example database bellow. Here is the code:

```
   database      user_id     hits

                    2         0
                    4         3
                    5         20
                    6         43
                    9         2
                    3         45
                    7         23
```

How I would want them outputted is this way. Here is the code:

```
   output:
      3
      6
      2
      4
      5
      7
      9
```

Basically I want to put 2 different ASC markups for sql. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Would i guess that you want users with fewer than 40 hits to be ordered by `user_id` ascending and more than forty to be ordered by `hits` descending?

If so, use an order by with multiple conditions:

```
order by (hits <= 40) desc,
         (case when hits <= 40 then user_id end) asc,
         (case when hits > 40 then hits end) desc;
```